# how can i remove trailing slashes form the url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am having an issue with the trailing slashes at the end of the URL. I check the URL redirection online and the result shows me that I am having too many redirects on my page so I need to reduce  those redirects I am having the following result of my link

```
https://example.com/xyz/pqr
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr/
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr//
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr///
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr/////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr//////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr///////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr////////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr/////////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr//////////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr///////////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr////////////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr/////////////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr//////////////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr///////////////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr////////////////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr/////////////////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr//////////////////
302 Found
https://example.com/xyz/pqr///////////////////
302 Found
```

how can i resolve this issue?? i am having no idea where i am going wrong..!! Any help would be aprpeciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=3842
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```

That's all what  i have in my htaccess code and the rest is just a 301 redirects and nothing more..!!

Comment: Post the code from .htaccess file that deals with redirection.

Comment: Well i have edited my question and added the htaccess code there. Please  check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a trailing slash using `.htaccess` you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: if i just want to check if it is redirecting properly or not  do i need to make any changes in the above code??? 301 means a permanant redirect before doing so i need to check first weather it is working or not.!